# Hide or revoke permissions to the .ssh directory for sftp and ftp access

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, debian, ftp, sftp

I dont want that the user has access to the ssh key via sftp and ftp. Is there a way to change the directory or revoke the permissions, even to see the .ssh directory ?
Have not found anything with google.

Im using debian 6

Comment: You can use chmod to change permissions and chown to change ownership. What problem do you have exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the authorized keys file needs to be read by the user that's login in, there is no way to prevent him/her from, at least, reading it.

However, you can place the public keys of authorized users in a custom path using the following directive:

```
    AuthorizedKeysFile
             Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used for user authentication.  AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during connection
             setup.  The following tokens are defined: %% is replaced by a literal ’%’, %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that
             user.  After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user’s home directory.  The default is “.ssh/authorized_keys”.
```

So using something like:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /some/path/authorized_keys/%u
```

will let you define a per-user file, in a controlled path outside users' `$HOME`, with read-only permissions and possibly owned by `root`.